# Verifying REST client, without calling the (actual) server?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, cxf-client

Given a third-party web-app which provides REST API and a Java application as REST client for it.

What is the best approach to test and verify that the rest paths, parameters and payloads are valid **in the client side** and they are compatible with the server api, ***without dealing with the real REST server***?

In other words, I would like to have unit/integration test (or something similar) to verify the requests (from client), without calling the real server.

ps: apache cxf is used to develop the client.

Comment: Create a stub or mock that pretends to be the Real Server and then verifies that the requests are correct? I'm assuming you have some sort of WSDL/WADL for the third-party web-app?

Comment: @DanTemple, Then how should I verify the stub or mock? The same problem.

Comment: The stub/mock would pretend to be the third party REST API. If your client could successfully make requests to the stub/mock, then the client is working as expected. Granted this does add the maintenance of the stub/mock into your scope, but if you've got a WSDL/WADL, then cxf can build a service from that pretty easily.

Comment: @DanTemple with stub/mock I can make sure my client is working successfully with my stub/mock implementation. but How i can make sure my stub is behaving as real server? I want to make sure my client is compatible with my server, not the stub or mock.